# How to randomize tasks.loop timer in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i tried this:

```
timer = 15
random_timer = timer
channel = 108728307283
@tasks.loop(seconds = random_timer)
async def hello():
    await channel.send("Hello!")
    random_timer = timer + random.randint(1, 20)
hello.start()
```

My guess is that while a loop is running, it only looks at the value when it is run for the first time, so how do I set this random_timer value back to seconds without stopping the loop? In short, what should I do to send a message to a channel in a random time between 15-35 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify the total amount of iterations before exiting the loop, we can pass `count` to `@tasks.loop()`

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = random_timer, count=random.randint(15,35))
```

To change the interval timing of our loop during iteration, You can use `function.change_interval()`

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = random_timer, count=random.randint(15,35))
async def hello():
    await channel.send("Hello!")
    hello.change_interval(seconds=timer + random.randint(1, 20))
```